# Using cURL to parse xml file returns no start tag

Tags: php, xml, curl

This is the cURL setup I am using:

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'url to xml file');

    //return the transfer as a string
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,400);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    // $output contains the output string
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    // close curl resource to free up system resources
    curl_close($ch);
```

And for some reason I get the following error:

```
[error] [php] simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Start tag expected, '<' not found (/path/to/rendered/file/file.php
```

When I call the xml url in the browser I get valid xml so what is causing this error?

Kind regards,

Pim

Comment: You're not "using curl to parse XML"

Answer (score 0):

You should check $output variable contents. Just do:

```
echo $output;
```

and make sure it has your XML document. Generally if some error has occurred cURL will return you a document containing the error and thus you would be able to see why it fails.

Also using curl_errno() function makes sense: it should be 0 if everything is OK with request.

Comment: Using var_dump it returns this:

string(3443) "
                                                                                                                                                                 "

Comment: Looks like binary string: it is 3443 bytes long but not shown. You should do file_put_contents("file.bin", $output); and then inspect contents of the file. Quite likely it is gzip stream which was not uncompressed by cURL: add curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_ENCODING , "gzip"); to your script and try again.

Comment: Mehhh, still the same response when using curlopt gzip. strange thing is file.bin file is not generated :(

Comment: Rights issue? If you run your script under web server then you can save the file only to the directory where web server is allowed to write.

Comment: I execute it by running it in the browser... maybe fopen construction?

Comment: fopen and file_put_contents do the same thing in the end. Running it in the browser means that it script runs under web server: try to save to /tmp folder - usually web server can write there

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, some other stuff also needed some attention. I'll look into your tips.

Comment: Oke... akward... when I view the source from the var_dump I see valid xml. But why do I then get the error that made me trigger this question?

Comment: Well... At least you know that cURL is not at blame. From your question I cannot see full PHP code which handles your XML. Do you mind to post it? Generally such error says "whatever you fed into me is not an XML" - I believe your $output does not make it to simplexml_load_string() for some reason, nothing to do with cURL

Comment: Oke.. here more info about this... I have 4 servers executing this exact same code, 3 out of 4 do as is told. One is showing the error message before... How is this possble? The code and the url to the xml is all exactly the same...